# How to write regex of time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex, which will give in format **`00:00`** `(hour:minutes)` in 24 hours format.

With no spaces is allowed.

- First part `'00'` will be numbers(hours) and including / between `00` to `23`.
- Second part `':'` will be always colon there.
- Third part `'00'` will be numbers(minutes) and including / between `00` to `59`.

I tried with `/\s/g.test(stringToBeChecked)`. This will return if spaces are present in between characters.

Please give me wright solution as I am not familar with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

Comment: Thanks, will you please give me an brief explanation, what is written above?

Comment: ^: string must start with. `[01]`: 0 or 1, followed by `\d` - digit (0-9), OR (`|`) 2 followed by digit from 0 to 3 (`[0-3]`). Then `:`, followed by digit from 0 to 5, and followed by any digit (`\d`), and string must finish here (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regular expression -

```
    ((([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:)([0-5][0-9]))
```